# How to copy a small slice to the end of a bigger slice

Tags: arrays, go

I'm looking for the equivalent of Java `System.arraycopy()`

Let's say I have 2 slices

```
small := make([]byte, 4)
big := make([]byte, 10)
```

I'd like to copy the content of `small` to `big` at position 6 (the bytes of `small` being the last bytes of `big`

The only way I found is to write a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the builtin [copy](https://godoc.org/builtin#copy) function:

```
copy(big[6:], small)
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I was looking for. However, now I understand better, I'm not sure I agree with your editing my question. I think the slices are a mean to access the array (so in my question, array was the right terminology I think)

Comment: @YaFred The code in question uses slices, not arrays. If you had asked how to copy a [4]byte the end of a [10]byte, then array would have been the correct term to use.

Comment: because of make() ... Ok, I get it now.

Comment: It's because small and big are slices, not arrays. It's unimportant that the slice was created with make.